# Manager for folder of images

Tags: php, jquery, mage

I am a big fan of jquery and PHP. I have already found a solution to batch upload jpg with resizing. I am now on a looking for a solution to MANAGE photo list

**must i need :** 
view (thumbnail)
edit name (simple)
delete (single click)

**Will be cool :** 
crop
color correct
sharpen

So the question, does anybody know a framework or php script that do the must (view,edit name, delete picture) WITHOUT a database

Overall, there will be a folder that you fill with jpg, upload with ajax, slideshow with jquery, manage with php, everything dynamic. If it found 5 photos in the folder, slideshow thos 5 and/or manage, if 500 fo the same no question ask !

Thanks in advance for your great solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search turned up [phpGraphy](http://phpgraphy.sourceforge.net/). It has thumbnails and administration and does not use a database.

Comment: look interesting.. will try it tonight

Comment: I try the program... good idea, bad execution.... too complicated... to DOS based !